# Delete duplicates (Names) keeping one entry

Tags: duplicates

I have the following table:

```
Employee_ID    Employee_Name
21             Berger, Johan
24             Smith, John
24             Smith, John
33             Specter, Harvey
33             Specter, Harvey
45             Peterson, Lisa
45             Peterson, Lisa
```

At the end I would like to have:

```
Employee_ID    Employee_Name
21             Berger, Johan
24             Smith, John
33             Specter, Harvey
45             Peterson, Lisa
```

Could you please help?
Thanks,
A

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

HI dude I am taking it you are using sql server

First, insert an identity column in that table by using the following code:

> ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
>
> DELETE FROM dbo.Employee WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID ) _   FROM
>   dbo.Employee GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID,Employee_Name )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE (Employee_ID, Employee_Name,DuplicateCount)
    AS
    (
      SELECT Employee_ID, Employee_Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee_ID, Employee_Name ORDER BY Employee_ID) AS  DuplicateCount
      FROM Employee
    )
    DELETE
    FROM CTE
      WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
```

Working SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ef1e/1